# How to create a text file with windows line ending (CRLF) using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a dynamic frame created with the required data. I'm using pyspark in aws glue job. I'm creating a file as below

```
df_final_data.coalesce.write.format("text").option("mode", "append").save(var_bucket)
```

But this is creating a file with LF line endings.

How can I create a file with CRLF line endings or is there a way to replace these LF to CRLF after the file is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `lineSep` parameter:

```py
df_final_data.coalesce.write.format("text").option("lineSep", "\r\n").option("mode", "append").save(var_bucket)
```